# How do I push "fizz" into the array, and remove the number it should be replacing?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is my code so far.  My console.log is printing the array in sequential numbers each time I run the function.  I want "fizz" to be printed when count%3===0, which it's doing, but also adding 3 to the array.  I want the array to look like this [1, 2, "fizz", 4, 5, "fizz", ].

```
var output = [];
var count = 1
function fizzBuzz(){
output.push(count);
count++;

console.log(output);

if (count % 3 == 0){ 
 output.push("fizz");
}
```

Comment: *Don't* push `count` into the array when `count % 3 == 0`…!? Simply use of `if..else`…

Comment: You could `pop()` it. Alternatively, don't push the number until you find out there was no word to use instead of it (that is, it is not a multiple of 3 )

Answer (score 0):

modify your code with this

```js
var output = [];
var count = 1;
function fizzBuzz() {
  if (count % 3 == 0) {
    output.push("fizz");
  } else {
    output.push(count);
  }
  count++;
  console.log(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect so here are two solutions :

```js
        var output1 = [];
        var count1 = 0;
        
        function fizzBuzz(){
            count1++;
            if (count1 % 3 == 0){ 
                output1.push("fizz");
            }else{
                output1.push(count1);
            }
        }
        
        var output2 = [];
        var count2 = 0;
        
        function fooBuzz(){
            count2++;
            if (count2 % 3 == 0){ 
                output2.push(count2);
                output2.push("foo");
            }else{
                output2.push(count2);
            }
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){
            fizzBuzz();
        }
        for(var j = 0; j<6; j++){
            fooBuzz();
        }
        console.log(output1);
  /* output
[
  1,
  2,
  "fizz",
  4,
  5,
  "fizz"
]
*/
        console.log(output2);
/* output
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  "foo",
  4,
  5,
  6,
  "foo"
]
*/
```